# Format vector string on stdout

Tags: c++, string, vector

So for this program I'm writing for class I have to format a vector string into standard output. I get how to do it with just strings with the 'printf' function but I don't understand how to do it with this.

Here's what I got:

```
void put(vector<string> ngram){
while(!(cin.eof())){ ///experimental. trying to read text in string then output in stdout. 
printf(ngram, i);///
```

Comment: don't you mean `printf`?

Comment: yes, let me fix that.

Comment: What do you intent to do? If you just want to `format a vector string into standard output`, why you need `while(!(cin.eof()))`?

Comment: ok, now what is `i`? Why are you using `cin`? You haven't specified a format argument to `printf` (even when printing strings you should use a format of `%s` and pass the string as an argument). See this page for some details: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I can't read a lot out of your question but from what I understood, you want to print a vector of strings to the standard output!? This would work like this:

```
void put(std::vector<std::string> ngram){
   for(int i=0; i<ngram.size(); i++)
   {
      //for each element in ngram do:
      //here you have multiple options:
      //I prefer std::cout like this:
      std::cout<<ngram.at(i)<<std::endl;
      //or if you want to use printf:
      printf(ngram.at(i).c_str());
   }
   //done...
   return;
}
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes! Sorry if I was pretty blunt on explaining what I was trying to do. I'm pretty new to this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want each item on a single line:

```
void put(const std::vector<std::string> &ngram) {

    // Use an iterator to go over each item in the vector and print it.
    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = ngram.begin(), end = ngram.end(); it != end; ++it) {

        // It is an iterator that can be used to access each string in the vector.
        // The std::string c_str() method is used to get a c-style character array that printf() can use.
        printf("%s\n", it->c_str());

    }

}
```